# MySQL table creation insanely slow

Tags: mysql, performance

A simple table creation on one of my MySQL databases takes forever:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE blah (id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (16.58 sec)
```

The machine is quite idle:

```
01:21:26 PM       CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
01:21:27 PM       all      0.50      0.00      0.21      0.00      0.00     99.29
```

Any ideas how to investigate this?

**EDIT**: Following [DTest's advice](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27813/972), this is the execution profile:

```
mysql> SHOW PROFILE FOR QUERY 1;
+----------------------+----------+
| Status               | Duration |
+----------------------+----------+
| starting             | 0.000044 |
| checking permissions | 0.000024 |
| creating table       | 8.668129 |
| After create         | 0.000014 |
| query end            | 0.000005 |
| freeing items        | 0.000028 |
| logging slow query   | 0.000004 |
| logging slow query   | 0.000206 |
| cleaning up          | 0.000006 |
+----------------------+----------+
```

Comment: @Phil A physical machine with some 16GB of memory.

Comment: @Phil It's a production server with many MySQL operations, so the disk shouldn't be idle.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would briefly turn on [profiling](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-profile.html) to get an idea of what takes so long. An example using mysql's CLI:

```
SET profiling = 1;
CREATE TABLE blah (id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
SET profiling = 0;
```

You should get a response something like this:

```
mysql> SHOW PROFILES;
| Query_ID | Duration   | Query |
+----------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|        1 | 0.00913800 | CREATE TABLE blah (id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY) |
+----------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW PROFILE FOR QUERY 1;
+----------------------+----------+
| Status               | Duration |
+----------------------+----------+
| starting             | 0.000071 |
| checking permissions | 0.000007 |
| Opening tables       | 0.001698 |
| System lock          | 0.000043 |
| creating table       | 0.007260 |
| After create         | 0.000004 |
| query end            | 0.000004 |
| closing tables       | 0.000015 |
| freeing items        | 0.000031 |
| logging slow query   | 0.000002 |
| cleaning up          | 0.000003 |
+----------------------+----------+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: @AdamMatan not sure if you read the profiling documentation, but there are other flags for showing profile of the query `CPU`, `BLOCK IO` etc that might help you on the 'creating table' stage.

Comment: what i dont get is where is the suggestion for lowering the time , the profiler does show the time under creating table but where is the solution to fix it ?