# Slow "CREATE TABLE" and "TRUNCATE" on MySQL / MariaDB

Tags: mysql, performance, mariadb

I am fighting with performance issues on a local MariaDB instance.

Fun thing: I previously had problems with all my INSERT and UPDATE and DELETE queries. This got signigicantly faster (~40ms -> less than 1ms) by changing the innodb_flush_method from O_DIRECT to ALL_O_DIRECT (undoing a previous change), following a suggestion on stackexchange. This is contrary to all other advice I found on the web, that suggests to use O_DIRECT.

EDIT: Not sure anymore about the above. Seen slow INSERT and UPDATE queries again.

What still remains is TRUNCATE and CREATE TABLE being very slow:
~150ms to CREATE TABLE, with a quite simple table structure (InnoDB).
~150ms to TRUNCATE this table, while it is already empty.

All of that in an otherwise empty database, and after purging all the ibdata1 and stuff, as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3456885/246724.

The same queries are significantly faster (mysql says 0.00 seconds) on a different machine (my webserver).

### Profiling results

Using the awesome [profiling](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27813/59895) [feature](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-profile.html), I found that the bottleneck is in the 'creating table' step for CREATE, and in the 'After table lock' step for TRUNCATE.

TRUNCATE:

```
+------------------------------+----------+
| Status                       | Duration |
+------------------------------+----------+
| starting                     | 0.000038 |
| checking permissions         | 0.000042 |
| Opening tables               | 0.000093 |
| After opening tables         | 0.000007 |
| System lock                  | 0.000005 |
| Table lock                   | 0.000003 |
| After table lock             | 0.116224 |
| Waiting for query cache lock | 0.000007 |
| After table lock             | 0.000004 |
| query end                    | 0.000011 |
| closing tables               | 0.000011 |
| freeing items                | 0.000004 |
| updating status              | 0.000010 |
| cleaning up                  | 0.000003 |
+------------------------------+----------+
```

CREATE TABLE:

```
+----------------------+----------+
| Status               | Duration |
+----------------------+----------+
| starting             | 0.000093 |
| checking permissions | 0.000013 |
| Opening tables       | 0.000013 |
| After opening tables | 0.000004 |
| System lock          | 0.000002 |
| Table lock           | 0.000002 |
| After table lock     | 0.000016 |
| creating table       | 0.155836 |
| After create         | 0.000006 |
| query end            | 0.000003 |
| closing tables       | 0.000005 |
| freeing items        | 0.000003 |
| updating status      | 0.000007 |
| cleaning up          | 0.000002 |
+----------------------+----------+
```

When using `SHOW PROFILE ALL FOR QUERY 10`, I get a lot of zeros in CPU_*, Context_*, Block_ops_*,  Messages_*, Page_faults_*, Swaps.

But the non-zero table cells are:

TRUNCATE:
"After table lock" + "Context_voluntary" -> 10
"After table lock" + "Block_ops_out" -> 269

CREATE TABLE:
"creating table" + "Context_voluntary" -> 10
"creating table" + "Block_ops_out" -> 276

Source:
TRUNCATE "After table lock" -> mysql_lock_tables lock.cc 326
CREATE TABLE "creating table" -> create_table_impl sql_table.cc 4775

### Table structure

The table structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE `cache_bootstrap` (
`cid` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'Primary Key: Unique cache ID.',
`data` longblob COMMENT 'A collection of data to cache.',
`expire` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'A Unix timestamp indicating when the cache entry should expire, or 0 for never.',
`created` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'A Unix timestamp indicating when the cache entry was created.',
`serialized` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'A flag to indicate whether content is serialized (1) or not (0).',
PRIMARY KEY (`cid`),
KEY `expire` (`expire`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Cache table for data required to bootstrap Drupal, may be...';
```

Simplifying this to just one column, either string key or auto-increment, still leaves me with ~100ms for CREATE TABLE and TRUNCATE. But the Context_voluntary changes to 2, and the Block_ops_out changes to 16.

### System specs on desktop, where this issue occurs

MySQL version:
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.15-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

OS: Manjaro / Arch Linux.

Memory: 16 GB
CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4570 CPU @ 3.20GHz
Board: ASRock H97 Pro4
HDD (/dev/sda): WDC WD30EZRX-00DC0B0, 3TB, connected with SATA
HDD Partitions:
/dev/sda5 mounted to /, 33% full, 52.1GB total, ext4
/dev/sda4 mounted to /home, 34% full, 524GB total, ext4
Other partitions probably not relevant here.. /var/lib/mysql is on /dev/sda5.
Second HDD probably not relevant here.

### System spec on webserver, where these queries are much faster

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.73, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.1

Memory: 1GB
CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5520  @ 2.27GHz

Since this is a virtual machine provided by a hosting company, it won't let me see info about harddrives.

Comment: Could you give your machine spec (RAM, CPU, Disk (RAID?))?

Comment: Also, the spec of the machine where it is fast?

Comment: What exactly do you want to know? Is there a command that I can run on either machine and it will give you the infos you need?

Comment: RAM? The relevant bits of "more /proc/meminfo" (**not** all). CPU? The relevant bits of "more /proc/cpuinfo". HDD? Disk config - RAID info &c. - not sure about exact command.

Comment: I added some specs. I hope this is the relevant info that you need.

Comment: I assume the most relevant part is the HDD. The other parts (memory, CPU) are quite modern, and htop did not show any peak in memory or CPU usage. Swap untouched.

Comment: "won't let me see info about harddrives". Surely they provide specs of some sort - at least a speed guestimate? Anyway, it's definitely about the HDD. Anyway, you shouldn't be worrying about the speed of DDL (inc. TRUNCATE). Those ops should be **very** rare during day to day operations.

Comment: This is not up to me to decide. I am working with a CMS (Drupal), and this does quite a lot of TRUNCATE and INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE when clearing database caches (and my initial observation that the INSERTs were faster does not really hold). Yes, there are other cache options, but they are hard to setup. I am also dealing with data imports, which also have a lot of write queries. The main point is, this is all much much slower than it needs to be, from comparing the two machines.

Comment: So if it is the disk, what can I investigate?

Comment: See my answer below - I haven't finished investigating myself.

Comment: I confirm I can reproduce this as well.
423 tables created in 17 seconds (initially: 27 seconds, before setting innodb_flush_method=ALL_O_DIRECT, innodb_stats_persistent = 0 and removing innodb_file_per_table).
But the strangest thing is that it takes only 1.5s on the same machine but inside a vagrant.
Vagrant's sql server: mysql 5.6.33-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
Host sql server: 10.0.28-MariaDB
I wonder if it is not because on the host, all files are separately synced to disk, while for vagrant, all file changes are synced to a unique file, thanks to virtualization.

Answer (score 2):

I experimented with this and found something very interesting.

Running Fedora release 20 (Heisenbug) 3.11.10-301.fc20.x86_64, 2GB RAM (I know!), 2 processor Intel centrino.

If you enable the Performance Schema (P_S), the times seem to drop dramatically. Why this is, I simply don't know - the P_S is for monitoring, and not changing anything. I have put what I put in my my.cnf at the end.

Could you test this for your 3 scenarios (CREATE, TRUNCATE & DELETE) running your server using the new my.cnf. If you obtain similar results to mine, then we can investigate further.

Strangely, as far as I can see, the client reports a time of approx 0.3 seconds for me for all of my experiments - but the results from the profiling seem very different. Still puzzling through this one.

Below are my results just for the CREATE table statement before and after enabling the performance schema.

Before enabling P_S.

```
mysql> show profile for CREATE TABLE cache_bootstrap;
+----------------------+----------+
| Status               | Duration |
+----------------------+----------+
| starting             | 0.000290 |
| checking permissions | 0.000021 |
| Opening tables       | 0.000141 |
| creating table       | 0.365769 |  <<====
| After create         | 0.000037 |
| query end            | 0.000023 |
| closing tables       | 0.000018 |
| freeing items        | 0.000114 |
| cleaning up          | 0.000030 |
+----------------------+----------+
9 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

After enabling P_S

```
mysql> show profile for CREATE TABLE cache_bootstrap;
+----------------------+----------+
| Status               | Duration |
+----------------------+----------+
| starting             | 0.000188 |
| checking permissions | 0.000131 |
| query end            | 0.000015 |
| closing tables       | 0.000020 |
| freeing items        | 0.000068 |
| cleaning up          | 0.000052 |
+----------------------+----------+
6 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

MariaDB

Before enabling P_S

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.33 sec)

```
MariaDB [test]> show profile for CREATE TABLE cache_bootstrap;
+----------------------+----------+
| Status               | Duration |
+----------------------+----------+
| starting             | 0.000321 |
| checking permissions | 0.000024 |
| Opening tables       | 0.000073 |
| After opening tables | 0.000017 |
| System lock          | 0.000011 |
| Table lock           | 0.000019 |
| After opening tables | 0.000056 |
| creating table       | 0.328769 |  <<======
| After create         | 0.000043 |
| query end            | 0.000026 |
| closing tables       | 0.000022 |
| freeing items        | 0.000043 |
| updating status      | 0.000050 |
| cleaning up          | 0.000039 |
+----------------------+----------+
14 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

After enabling P_S on MariaDB

```
MariaDB [test]> show profile for CREATE TABLE cache_bootstrap
+----------------------+----------+
| Status               | Duration |
+----------------------+----------+
| starting             | 0.000311 |
| checking permissions | 0.000024 |
| Opening tables       | 0.000044 |
| After opening tables | 0.000038 |
| System lock          | 0.000014 |
| Table lock           | 0.000012 |
| After opening tables | 0.000347 |
| After create         | 0.000015 |
| query end            | 0.000014 |
| closing tables       | 0.000021 |
| freeing items        | 0.000014 |
| updating status      | 0.000026 |
| cleaning up          | 0.000034 |
+----------------------+----------+
13 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

To be added in the [mysqld] section of my.cnf

```
[mysqld]

performance_schema
performance_schema_instrument = '%=on'
performance_schema_consumer_events_stages_current = ON
performance_schema_consumer_events_stages_history = ON
performance_schema_consumer_events_stages_history_long = ON
performance_schema_consumer_events_statements_history = ON
performance_schema_consumer_events_statements_history_long = ON
performance_schema_consumer_events_waits_current = ON
performance_schema_consumer_events_waits_history = ON
performance_schema_consumer_events_waits_history_long = ON
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not change anything for me. Changed the my.cnf, sudo systemctl restart mysqld, run the query again.. (with new table name). No change :(

Comment: oh, i have not checked the profiling yet! just the time reported by the client.. one momentito

Comment: no, profile looks the same.
I am going to do some more tests later, out of the house for now.

Comment: Have one for me! :-)

Comment: But interesting that you somehow do reproduce the crazy 0.3* second duration. It really should not be that long.

Comment: Do you want to move this to chat - I'm good with that.

Answer (score 1):

O_DIRECT vs. ALL_O_DIRECT -- depends on OS, HDD vs SDD, and distribution of files across multiple filesystems.  Probably ALL_O_DIRECT is best for your config.

Was it previously "ext4"?  That is not necessarily as good as XFS or ZFS.

What is the value of `innodb_file_per_table` when doing `CREATE TABLE`?
`OFF` (the old default) led to writing the data and indexes to the already-open file `ibdata1`
`ON` (the new default) requires creating a `.ibd` file.

In general, `ON` is better for large tables; potentially worse for small tables.

`TRUNCATE`, if I am not mistaken, is `DROP` + `CREATE`.

Comment: I have innodb_file_per_table on, because yes, the tables can get quite large. But the same is the case on my server vm. So, you are saying that creating the file for a new table can be slow depending on the filesystem? This does make sense, and is something I should look into. Is there a way to test this (speed of file creation) outside mysql? E.g. git clone creates a ton of files, but it is blazingly fast (if I clone from another folder, not from the web)